# flutter overlay outside its parent

Tags: flutter, overlay

I need to create a an overlay which isn't attached to the standard scaffold but rather its own parent and it needs to be displayed outside of its parent limits:
The overlay has to be owned by a parent as I'm using Providers and the given provider type can be used on multiple branches and as such they can't be placed at the top of the app.

The intent in the example is that the 'red' container will display over the  lightblue container. Instead it is displayed underneath.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage());
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Material(
        child: Flex(direction: Axis.vertical, children: [
      Expanded(flex: 1, child: Container(color: Colors.lightBlue)),
      Container(
          color: Colors.teal,
          height: 100,
          child: Overlay(initialEntries: [
            OverlayEntry(
                builder: (context) => Positioned(bottom: 90, left: 20,
                    child: Container(
                              width: 40, height: 40, color: Colors.red)))
                    ])
          )
    ]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the existing Overlay `Overlay.of(context)` from the Navigator instead of creating a new one. Inserting an OverlayEntry in the existing Overlay will always put it on top of your screen.

But in your example you might be better off with a Stack. You can use a Positioned Widget there too.

Answer (score 0):

you can share Overlay.of(context) (it's OverlayState) of parent, to children by using InheritedWidget , and use [NameOfInheritedWidget].of(context).insert(entity) from child's context